# p-norm and relative relations questions

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

Let $\left | x \right |_{p}=(|x_1|^p+...+|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$ denote the $p$-norm of the vector $x\in\mathbb{R}_n$, $\infty\ge p\ge1$.

Let $B_{r}^{p}$={$x\in\mathbb{R}_n : |x|_p\leq r$}.

1)Is there a $c>0$ such that $B_{1/c}^{2}\subseteq B_{1}^{\infty }\subseteq B_{c}^{2}$? If so, what is the smallest such $c$?

2)Given $1≤p<q<∞$, is there a $c>0$ such that $B_{1/c}^{p}\subseteq B_{1}^{q }\subseteq B_{c}^{p}$?

Comment: here what's the definition of $B_{1}^{\infty  }$?

Comment: $\|x\|_\infty = \max\{|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|\}$.

Comment: I changed {$x\in\mathbb{R}_n : |x|_p\leq r$} to $\{x\in\mathbb{R}_n : |x|_p\leq r\}$.  There's no need for the braces to be outside of TeX.

Comment: Reposted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/276519/7003

Comment: No one help me???

Comment: @i_a_n: [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) and [FAQ on homework](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question). Please read carefully. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For one fixed $n$?  Yes.  All norms on $\mathbb R^n$ compatible with the usual topology are "equivalent" in this sense.  (answers both 1 and 2)

The smallest such $c$, offhand I don't know.  But would consult perhaps Hardy, Littlewood, Polya, *Inequalities*.

Comment: $c=1$ always works for one side (and is tight) for any $p \geq 1$. So, we really only have to work with the other side. For the other side, I didn't check, but just consider all coordinates equal (for part 1)

Comment: cardinal: What's the "side"? and what about part 2)?