# p-norm and relations questions

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [p-norm and relative relations questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276157/p-norm-and-relative-relations-questions)

Let $\left | x \right |_{p}=(|x_1|^p+\cdots+|x_n|^p)^{1/p}$ denote the $p$-norm of the vector $x\in\mathbb{R}_n$, $\infty\ge p\ge1$.

Let $B_r^p=\{x\in\mathbb{R}_n : |x|_p\leq r\}$.

1)Is there a $c>0$ such that $B_{1/c}^2 \subseteq B_1^\infty \subseteq B_c^2$? If so, what is the smallest such $c$?
2)Given $1≤p<q<\infty$, is there a $c>0$ such that $B_{1/c}^p \subseteq B_1^q \subseteq B_{c}^{p}$?